# ViewBag as a holder of session models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This is more of a high-level question than anything else.

I have a MVC project which, among other things, manages users.
I am currently sticking to a more strict approach that on my view pages I only use a model which is declared, meaning that I have a:

```
@model MVCApp.Models.SomeModel
```

At the top of each View.cshtml

There are some pages that require more than 1 model. At this point I consolidate the 2 models into 1, and send it to the view as one model.

Here comes the tricky part. Let's say I have some model which holds the user data. That user data is stored in the session cookies (typical Forms Authentication). It seems weird to me that I now have to wrap each and every model I use with my own model that holds both the User Model and the model which I want to use inside that View.

The question that I ask myself is why not pass the User Model to the ViewBag and use it inside the View. Why is that considered to be bad practice? It allows me to attach that model to every page without having to ultimately duplicate all my models.

I'd love to get some guidance. I might be looking at this the wrong way. Any help will be much obliged.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why ViewBag should be avoided:

- ViewBag is weakly typed
- You don't get Intellisense in the view
- Your view is a mixture of ViewBag and a view model and your view gets information from different places instead of centralizing everything into a strongly typed view model
- ViewBag doesn't work with strongly typed helpers and expressions because dynamic types cannot be used with extension methods (that's not a limitation of ASP.NET MVC, it's .NET => you cannot dispatch extension methods on dynamic types)
- Due to this weak typing nature of ViewBag you will have to cast in your views turning them into spaghetti code because HTML helpers expect specific types to be passed as arguments
- ... this list goes on (I really don't have time to fill it but it is very large list)

So now that we know that ViewBag is bad and shouldn't be used there are different ways you could solve this requirement by using view models.

One possibility is to use the [Html.Action helper](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) which allows you to insert some portion of HTML in the view by going through a full Controller/Model/View lifecycle. This way you could have a commonly used widget without interfering with your main view model.

Another possibility is to have a base view model which will contain a property representing user details and which will be populated by a custom global action filter that could executed everytime a controller action has finished executing and returned a view result. The action filter could intercept this view result, read the authentication cookie information and set the view model property. This assumes that all your view models derive from the common base view model. This obviously makes sense if you need to display this user information on each page.

For example:

```
public class UserInfoInjectorAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
        if (result == null)
        { 
            // the controller action didn't return any view result => no need to continue
            return;
        }

        var model = result.Model as BaseViewModel;
        if (model == null)
        {
            // the controller action didn't pass a model or the model passed to the view
            // doesn't derive from the common base view model that will contain 
            // the user info property => no need to continbue any further
            return;
        }

        model.UserInfo = ... go ahead and read the forms authentication cookie
                             userData portion and extract the information
                             you are looking for
    }
}
```

Now all that's left is to register this action filter as a global action filter and it will be applied on all controller actions.

Now if all your view models derive from this `BaseViewModel` you will know that once you arrive in the view the UserInfo property will be populated with the relevant information without polluting all your controller actions with code that does the fetching of this property. And still you get strong typing in the view => no ViewBag (youpeeee).

Of course depending on your specific scenario there might be other ways to achieve that (obviously not involving any `ViewBag`).

Comment: I think you tried to instruct him to use Html.RenderAction, to render a partial view through the Controller. I that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's one possibility to render the user information widget that could be repeated on each view. The Html.Action helper could be used in the _Layout in this case.

Comment: Hey Darin, Thanks for the answer. The only problem that I have is that I am working with a business layer, which is implemented in .NET. That business layer has its own models, and since it is not only oriented to my MVC project, I don't want to change the models there. Your answer means that I have to write my own Web-Model (which holds the user) and I do have to wrap each model with my own. Is that the situation? Thanks.

Comment: @OmerAmsel, what you call `Web-Model` has a name: it's called `view model`. You should always use view models in an ASP.NET MVC application. Never pass your domain models to the views. That's one of the worst mistakes people do when designing ASP.NET MVC applications. You should always design view models which are classes specifically tailored for the needs of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can an [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.aspx) and in those Actions that load views which needs specific ViewBag items, you initialize them.

I don't recommend it, as it will be harder to mantains, but will be a generic approach which may solve your problems.